# Sitecore NextJS: How do I make the background image of a div editable in the Experience Editor?

Tags: next.js

I created a component in Sitecore Next Js React. The component is basically a full width banner. I need to set an image as the background of the parent dive and this should be editable through the experience editor.

How would I go about doing this in nextjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it similarly to react or with Next component.

1. Place image to public folder and add path to image in background-image property
2. Import image and place import to background-image property like this:

`backgroundImage: url(${bg.src})`

3. Use next/image component. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image
   This component make some optimization.
   You should place image in src prop like 1 variant or just pass image import, add layout = fill, and position: relative to parent.

Official demo: https://image-component.nextjs.gallery/background

Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image